# React-Native: Memory Leak with Dependency Variable

Tags: typescript, react-native

I ran into this issue by trying to resolve this warning from the eslint-plugin-react-hooks:

> warning  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'promisedObject'. Either include it or remove the dependency

Sounds simple enough. I added it, but now my app gets bogged down. The more my component renders/updates, the slower my app gets. I think that means that there's a memory leak or something. I do not have this issue when I do not have `promisedObject` in my dependency array.

```js
export default function MyComponent(props: MyProps): ReactElement {
  const [myObject, setMyObject] = useState<MyObject>(new MyObject());
  const promisedObject: Promise<MyObject> = useMyCustomHook();

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const storedObject = await promisedObject;
      if (storedObject != null) {
        setMyObject(storedObject);
      }
    })();
    // promisedObject causes a memory leak, I think
    // I could disable eslint for this line, but that's a last resort.
  }, [props.key, promisedObject]);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>
        {myObject.someValue()}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

A few things to keep in mind

- `myCustomHook()` is making calls to `AsyncStorage` if that's relevant
- `promisedObject` isn't necessary to be updated. I prefer it to only be loaded once.

What's going wrong here?

Comment: Is `promisedObject` being created anew on every render of `MyComponent`? If so, then the `useEffect` hook is going to be re-run on ever re-render.

Comment: `useMyCustomHook()` is calling `AsyncStorage` and then is using another library create a new `MyObject`, so it would be new every time. So that does sound like my problem, thank you! How can I get one initial load on my object without creating a new one every time?

Comment: If you memoize your custom hook and never pass it any args then it should always return the same object instance. Read up a bit on object referential equality if you're not already familiar with why `{ a: 1 } === { a: 1}` will evaluate to `false` Also, if you're sure you don't need the value in the dependency array, you can simply exclude it from the array. You can disable ESLint for a line for only a specific rule by including the rule name after `//eslint-disable-line [rule name]`, which is a lot safer.

Comment: I think this could be simplified by setting the object inside your custom hook, instead of returning a promise from a hook. You can call `useState` inside hooks without problem. Let me know if that would work for you

Comment: @AhmedGhoneim that was a good idea, but I tried this and it looks like I'm still seeing the slow-down even if I just pass the setter.